# Best way to transfer files between servers with Capistrano?

Tags: nginx, capistrano, capistrano3

I have a rails app that I deploy to an app server via Capistrano, and I want to figure out the best way to transfer some files that are built during the deploy to an nginx server.

I have thought about downloading the file to my deploy server and then copying the file back to nginx, but that seems like not the cleanest solution.

What is the best way is to transfer a file from my app server to my nginx server?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably build a custom task to scp or rsync the files.

Comment: upload! doesn't work and it will only search remote to remote